# Global destructors __do_global_dtors_aux

Tags: c++, c, destructor

I am having an issue that I am running into. My program has a double free or corruption error. When I debug it using gdb I see that one library calls the global destructor __do_global_dtors_aux. This is followed by SIGABORT. Now is it possible to change __do_global_dtors_aux and make it 
print the address of the deleted global object

Comment: You'd normally see that in the stacktrace in gdb, e.g. `#3  0x080485b7 in  mystruct::~mystruct (this=0x804a024 <my_global>) at t.cpp:5` , i.e. it was the variable `my_global` at address 0x804a024 (__do_global_dtors_aux is normally called for desctructors living in shared libraries, be sure to compile it with debug info)

Comment: C or C++, what is it? This symbol isn't defined in any of the standards, so it must be compiler specific? Which one is it?